# C Linked list, losing elements

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to write code that adds a linked list's element's numbers. But after addition I lose some of the elements. I can't find the errors. Here's my code:

```
void push(struct node** head_ref, int new_data){
    struct node* new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
    new_node->data  = new_data;
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
    (*head_ref)    = new_node;
}
void reverse(struct node** head_ref){
    struct node* prev   = NULL;
    struct node* current = *head_ref;
    struct node* next;
    while (current != NULL){
        next  = current->next;
        current->next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }
    *head_ref = prev;
}
struct node *shiftter(struct node *a, int index){
    struct node *temp = a;
    while(index > 0){
        append(&temp, 0);
        --index;
    }
    return temp;
}
struct node *add(struct node *fist, struct node *second){
    struct node *gudu = second;
    struct node *c = fist;
    struct node *hudu = NULL;
    reverse(&gudu);
    reverse(&c);
    while(c != NULL){
        push(&hudu, c->data + gudu->data);
        c = c->next;
        gudu = gudu->next;
    }
    while(gudu != NULL){
        push(&hudu, gudu->data);
        gudu = gudu->next;
    }
    return hudu;
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    struct node *a = NULL;
    struct node *b = NULL;
    push(&a , 1);
    push(&a , 2);
    push(&a , 3);
    push(&a , 4);
    push(&b , 5);
    push(&b , 1);
    push(&b , 2);
    push(&b , 4);
    printList(a);
    printf("\n");
    printList(b);
    printf("\n");
    b = shiftter(b,1);
    printList(b);
    printf("\n");
    printList(add(a, b));
    printf("\n");
    printList(a);
    printf("\n");
    printList(b);
    return 0;
}
```

My output is:

```
4 3 2 1 

4 2 1 5 

4 2 1 5 0  

4 6 4 7 1 

4

4
```

My program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: what does the function `shifter()` suppose to do?

Answer (score 2):

Even if the algorithm in `reverse` was correct, the problem in function `add` is simple: you reverse the lists and iterate through the resulting lists in parallel.  But you do not keep the new heads, so all nodes but the last are no longer referred to by anything.

You should keep the new heads and reverse them back to restore the original lists after you are done with the computation.

Better even: keep the lists in low to high digit order.

Comment: This appears to be an excellent continuation from my answer. Feel free to take what I have written and do what you need to form something more complete. Cited or not, I won't care... It is for the greater good that we, as a community, come up with a single cohesive answer that helps the OP learn. One more thing: If the remaining fragments of code happen to arise that make this question complete, feel free to ping me so I can help analyse that.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, your function named `reverse` doesn't do anything remotely close to `reverse`ing a list. It puts the last element (`prev`) at the head of the list, but that's as close as it gets... The rest of the logic is cloudy at best.Shouldn't it be modifying the last element's `->next` member, to point to the second-to-last element? This is where I believe the source of your missing elements is.

P.S. We still don't have the complete program necessary to definitively answer this question. Please ping me once you update the question with a complete/compilable testcase.

Comment: It would fit too, with about 114 chars left over.

Comment: @chux Can you link me to a meta telling me why this should be a comment, rather than an answer? Because so far [my research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297066/meta-meta-stack-overflow-when-should-i-answer-or-comment) indicates that this is a candidate for an answer.